Uploading a file from a managed app through Safari from a managed domain causes selected folder to disappear
I have the following MDM setup:

A browser is installed as managed (ex Firefox)
No managed domains
Managed app (Dropbox) with Files app integration.

This issue only occurs on iOS 18. iOS 17 works fine.
Trying to upload a file from managed Dropbox via managed Firefox by clicking on the Dropbox folder causes the folder to disappear and instead I am rerouted to the On My Phone directory.
On subsequent tries, sometimes the folder opens and I can see the files, but while scrolling the files disappear.
This makes it unable to upload any files from managed apps to managed apps.
It works correctly when both apps are unmanaged, and if only one is managed then the folders don't appear at all, which is intended.
Is this happening to anyone else? I also tried with Nextcloud and Google Drive, same issue.
Demo video: https://imgur.com/a/sVKLX9L
